# PHP Sessions strange behavior

Tags: php, session

I'm currently facing a strange problem in PHP.

I have two scripts, index.php which is the "homepage", and ajax.php which is a script called by an AJAX request.

**index.php**

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['test'] == "hello") {
  $_SESSION['test'] = "bleh";
  die();
 }

echo "here";
```

**ajax.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "hello";
```

So I go on index.php, then make an ajax call on ajax.php, I refresh index.php, and I actually expected to have a blank page, then refresh and have "here" printed; but actually the script never dies, like if $_SESSION['test'] had never been set to "hello".

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you start the session twice... you need to remove the call to `session_start` in `ajax.php`.

Comment: I added if (!session_id()) session_start(); in ajax.php, still the same problem.

Comment: Print out $_SESSION array after "session_start()" in index.php to see if it is empty or not after you make ajax call.

Comment: test is set to "bleh" after I make the ajax call and refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this at my system and it works as expected. Try calling the ajax.php page directly and see if you get the expected result, and then call the first one.

Also see if your browser get a cookie set and make sure it is not ignored so you get a new session every time the session starts.

Comment: I printed session_id() on both scripts, it's the same, so I guess cookie are alright

Comment: Maybe you can print your entire script - it will give us more context to work with. You can also use firebug and see how the calls to your scripts are done.